# Show/hide state from sidebar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have this states :

```
    function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('users', {
            url: '/users',
            template : '<ui-view  autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
            abstract: true,
            title: 'Collaborateurs',
            controller: "UserController",
            sidebarMeta: {
                icon: 'ion-grid',
                order: 300,
            },
        })
        .state('users.add', {
            url: '/add',
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/users/add/addUser.html',
            title: 'Ajouter',
            sidebarMeta: {
                order: 0,
            },
        });
}
```

Now with this the `users.add` state will appear on my sideBar but I want to make it appear only if user has a specific role.

Is this doable ?

Comment: What do you mean if user has a specific? do you mean a user is logged in?

Comment: Specific role, sorry forgot to add it

Comment: Can you post your html as well? putting ng-if on your navbar is one way to achieve it

Comment: Can you create a Working plunker

Comment: My code works well I'm asking if there's a solution to allow/deny access to a state relying on specific condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `resolve`. `resolve` allows you to accept or reject a promise, and resolve it when the state is loaded. If the promise is accepted, you can enter the state, and if not, you will not be able to load the state. You can easily write a `authenticate` service and inject it at your `resolve` function.

Supposing you have a service that does the authentication, called `AuthService`, and you have a `User` service that retrieves username, then you can do something like this:

```
.state('users.add', {
  url: '/add',
  templateUrl: 'app/pages/users/add/addUser.html',
  title: 'Ajouter',
  sidebarMeta: {
    order: 0,
  },
  resolve:{
    'RoleAuthorization':['AuthService','User',function(AuthService,User){
      return AuthService.hasRole(User.username);
      //or any other logic that you want to perform, as long as it returns a promise.
    }]
  }
});
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9sI5eDNHJF6nIZOtmOkD?p=preview) on how to do it.